# Linker error when user defined dll is refering another userdefined dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker-errors

I was trying to implement a protocol stack using Protocol Layer Design Pattern : 
http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/patterncatalog/protocol_layer.htm

In our project,I have all the layers as separate dlls.
The layers that i have are:

1. Application Layer dll
2. LLC Layer dll
3. MAC Layer dll
4. Physical Layer dll

I have another project in the same solution which implements the Design Pattern and 
has the implementations of the General functionalities of a protocol Layer.
All my layers are inheriting from the Protocol Layer Base class. The dependency between 
projects is as follows:
Protocol Layer Design Pattern dll: No dependency
Physical Layer dll: Protocol Design Pattern dll
MAC Layer dll: Protocol Design Pattern dll and Physical Layer dll
LLC Layer dll: Protocol Design Pattern dll and MAC Layer dll
Application Layer dll: Protocol Design Pattern dll and LLC Layer dll

Based on the design pattern, each of our layer has pointers to the layer above and below it.
And the flow that we designed is like: In application layer constructor we create an object of
 LLC Layer then LLC Layer creates Mac layer and MAC layer inturn creates physical Layer. They all are linked 
using pointers.

My Protocol Design Pattern project dll and Physical Layer dll builds properly. But other dll builds are giving 
linker error. Saying unresolved externals to the constructor of the underlying layer.
These are the errors which i am getting.

==================================

> 1. 1>phLayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>      virtual __thiscall CProtocolLayer::~CProtocolLayer(void)"
>      (??1CProtocolLayer@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function
>      __unwindfunclet$??0CPhysicalLayer@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z$0 1>phLayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>      __thiscall CReceiveProtocolHandler::CReceiveProtocolHandler(class CProtocolLayer *)"
>      (??0CReceiveProtocolHandler@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z) referenced
>      in    function "public: __thiscall
>      CPhysicalLayer::CPhysicalLayer(class    CProtocolLayer *)"
>      (??0CPhysicalLayer@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z)    1>phLayer.obj :
>      error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:    __thiscall
>      CTransmitProtocolHandler::CTransmitProtocolHandler(class
>      CProtocolLayer *)"
>      (??0CTransmitProtocolHandler@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z) referenced 
>      in function "public: __thiscall CPhysicalLayer::CPhysicalLayer(class
>      CProtocolLayer *)" (??0CPhysicalLayer@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z)
>      1>phLayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>      __thiscall CProtocolLayer::CProtocolLayer(class CProtocolLayer *,class CProtocolLayer *)" (??0CProtocolLayer@@QAE@PAV0@0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>      CPhysicalLayer::CPhysicalLayer(class CProtocolLayer *)"
>      (??0CPhysicalLayer@@QAE@PAVCProtocolLayer@@@Z) 1>phLayer.obj : error
>      LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall
>      CProtocolPacket::getBodyLength(void)"
>      (?getBodyLength@CProtocolPacket@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function
>      "public: virtual void __thiscall CPhysicalLayer::Data_req(class
>      CProtocolPacket *)"
>      (?Data_req@CPhysicalLayer@@UAEXPAVCProtocolPacket@@@Z) 1>phLayer.obj
>      : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>      CReceiveProtocolHandler::Handle_Receive(class CProtocolPacket *)"
>      (?Handle_Receive@CReceiveProtocolHandler@@QAEXPAVCProtocolPacket@@@Z)
>      referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
>      CPhysicalLayer::dataRead(void)" (?dataRead@CPhysicalLayer@@AAEXXZ)
>      1>phLayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>      void __thiscall CProtocolPacket::AddTrailer(int,char *)"
>      (?AddTrailer@CProtocolPacket@@QAEXHPAD@Z) referenced in function
>      "private: class CProtocolPacket __thiscall
>      CPhysicalLayer::convertToProtocolPacket(class
>      std::basic_string,class
>      std::allocator >)"
>      (?convertToProtocolPacket@CPhysicalLayer@@AAE?AVCProtocolPacket@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>      1>phLayer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>      void __thiscall CProtocolPacket::AddHeader(int,char *)"
>      (?AddHeader@CProtocolPacket@@QAEXHPAD@Z) referenced in function
>      "private: class CProtocolPacket __thiscall
>      CPhysicalLayer::convertToProtocolPacket(class
>      std::basic_string,class
>      std::allocator >)"
>      (?convertToProtocolPacket@CPhysicalLayer@@AAE?AVCProtocolPacket@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you building the exe?  I see that, you are facing only linker issues. Either you must be linking in the wrong order or there must be something, which went wrong. Try to link them in a correct order. This should solve the problem. If not, please provide more information.

Comment: We are not building exe, but we are tring to build a dll.

Comment: we want to have four separate dll's for each layer and another dll which contains the base class for all the layers (protocol Layer,Protocol Packet.etc as given in the prorotocol layer design pattern)

Comment: When i added reference to other projects , all the project got compiled. Is it ok ?

Comment: Have you worked out a solution? Are the dll's working fine? If yes, please close the question as answered.